# android when url audio streaming, music didn't stop

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Codes in below. when i add mediaplayer.stop();, media player hasn't stop. same thing for mediaplayer.pause(); if works. because icon is changing. But music hasn't stop. And i can't do debuging in android studio. Thanksi in advance.

```
package ceyhun.musicpuzzle.com;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button PlayPause;
private boolean boolMusicPlaying = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Baslamak();
}
private void Baslamak() {

PlayPause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PlayPause);
PlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    oynatim();


    }
});

}
private void oynatim() {

 final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

if (!boolMusicPlaying) {
    boolMusicPlaying = true;
    PlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getString(R.string.rihanna));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Baslamak();
  }
   else {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    //there is a problem. music hasn't stop.
    mediaPlayer.reset();

    PlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
    boolMusicPlaying = false;


    Baslamak();
  }
  }







  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run the "oynatim" method, you're instantiating a new class.

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

The line above should only be run once and not every time the method is run. I ran into the same problem when using Android Studio.

On a side note, you have to call mediaPlayer.prepare() or mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() if you want to get mediaPlayer out of a "stopped" states. This happens when you call mediaPlayer.stop().

Edit: Put the final MediaPlayer in the class and not the methods.

Comment: when i try add mediPlayer.prepare() or mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() and I click click button pause app stop. I can't understand how to fix this problem. Where can i put 'final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();' to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void stopPlaying {
            if ( mediaPlayer != null ) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
 }
```

> mediaPlayer is the instance of MediaPlayer in android that you first assign your URL and start play music :)